# Update and Delete Map/Reduce in HBase

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

I have a table that contains about have billion records. I want to change the key of these records i.e fetch a records change its key somehow, delete what was fetched save the new records ! Let us say for example my key is [time-accountId] and I want to change it to [account-time] 
I want to fetch entity create new with different key, delete the entity with [time-account] and save the new entity with [accout-time]

What is the best way to accomplish this task ?

I am thinking of M/R but how can I delete entities with M/R ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a mapreduce which will produce a Put and a Delete for each row of your table. Only a mapper is needed here since you don't need aggregation on your data, so skip the reducer:

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
    table,      // output table
    null,             // reducer class
    job);
```

Your mapper has to generate both Put and Delete, so the output value class to used is the Mutation (https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Mutation.html):

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
    table,        // input table
    scan,               // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
    MyMapper.class,     // mapper class
    ImmutableBytesWritable.class,         // mapper output key
    Mutation.class,  // mapper output value
    job);
```

Then your mapper will look like this:

```
Delete delete = ...
context.write(oldKey, delete);
Put put = ...
context.write(newKey, put);
```

Comment: I will try this one, it work then your answer is the accepted answer :P